# Update App Value from ng-Init

Tags: angularjs, ng-init

I have created a value for my module called Config. I want to pass in values from an ASP page (don't laugh). The values that I am passing in need to be available in all controllers used within my single page app. I am not sure how to address the Config value from the html.

**App.js**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('regApp', ['ngMessages', 'ui.router']);
```

**Config.js**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('regApp')
.value("Config", {
    siteGuid: '',
    apiUrl: ''
});
```

**default.asp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>

    <!-- angular -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="regApp" ng-init="Config.siteGuid = '<%= MY_SITE_GUID %>'">
    <div ui-view></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/controllers/CalendarController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/values/Config.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a script tag with a variable declaration in it. That variable will be available anywhere in the angular app as it will be in the `window` namespace scope

```
<head>
    <script> 
        var siteGuid = '<%= MY_SITE_GUID %>';
    </script>
    <!-- other head scripts and stuff -->
</head>
```

Then in your config.js

```
angular.module('regApp')
.value("Config", {
    siteGuid: window.siteGuid ,
    apiUrl: ''
});
```

Comment: I knew that it had to be something easy. I got the idea to use ng-Init because I was going to call an Init method, and I checked the Angular documentation for it. Their docs said not to do that and it gave me the idea to load my config data. I got excited. Then I got lost. Thanks for your help.